# calculating a function in matlab with very small values

Tags: matlab, precision, exponential, epsilon

I am making a function in matlab to compute the following function:

[image]

for this function we have:

[image]

This is my implementation in matlab of the function:

```
function [b]= exponential(e)
%b = ? 
b= (exp (e) -1)/e;
```

When I test the function with very small values, indeed the limit of the function is to 1, but when the number is very small (eg 1*e-20) the limit goes to zero? what is the explanation to this phenomenon?. Am I doing something wrong?.

```
x= 10e-1 , f (x)= 1.0517

x= 10e-5 , f (x)=  1.0000

x= 10e-10 , f (x)=  1.0000

x= 10e-20 , f (x)=  0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `exp(x)` is approx `1+x`, but is being evaluated as `1` due to the `1` being indistinguishable from `1+x` in the floating point representation. There is a MATLAB function `expm1(x)` (which is `exp(x)-1` implemented for small `x`) that avoids the problem and works well for small arguments:

```
>> x=1e-100;expm1(x)/x
ans =
     1
```

Comment: There is also `log1p(x)` giving `log(1+x)` implemented well for small `x`.

Answer (score 5):

I had to try my [LIMEST](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20058-adaptive-numerical-limit-estimation) tool out on it. As with any adaptive tool, it can be fooled, but it is usually pretty good.

```
fun = @(x) (exp(x) - 1)./x;
```

As you can see, fun has problems at zero.

```
fun(0)
ans =
   NaN
```

although if we evaluate fun near zero, we see it is near 1.

```
format long g
fun(1e-5)
ans =
          1.00000500000696
```

LIMEST succeeds, and even is able to provide an error estimate of the limit.

```
[lim,err] = limest(fun,0,'methodorder',3)

lim =
     1

err =
      2.50668568491927e-15
```

LIMEST uses a sequence of polynomial approximations, coupled with an adaptive Richardson extrapolation to generate both a limit estimate and a measure of the uncertainty on that limit.

So what problem are you seeing? The failure you saw is simple subtractive cancellation error. Thus, look at the value of

```
exp(1e-20)
ans =
     1
```

Even with format long g, the double precision value of exp(1e-20) is simply too close to 1 that when we subtract off 1, the result is an exact zero. Divide that by any non-zero value, and we get zero. Of course, when x is actually zero then we have a 0/0 condition, so NaN resulted when I tried that.

Lets see what happens in high precision. I'll use my HPF tool for that computation, and work in 64 decimal digits.

```
DefaultNumberOfDigits 64
exp(hpf('1e-20'))
ans =
1.000000000000000000010000000000000000000050000000000000000000166
```

See that when we sutract off 1, the difference between 1 and the exponential value is less than eps(1), so MATLAB must produce a zero value.

```
exp(hpf('1e-20')) - 1
ans =
1.000000000000000000005000000000000000000016666666666670000000000e-20
```

The question unasked is how I would choose to generate that function accurately in MATLAB. Clearly, you don't want to use brute force and define fun as I have, as you lose a great deal of accuracy. I'd probably just expand the Taylor series in a limited region around zero, and use fun as above for x significantly different from zero.

Comment: What is HPF tool ? is included on MatLab?

Comment: @Melkhiah66 - nope. Its the high precision toolbox I wrote in MATLAB. I'm still refining it. But you can also use the symbolic toolbox for similar computations.

Comment: @Melkhiah66 HPF is now on the file exchange

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with the precision of your numbers. In short, the default precision for MATLAB is 5 digits. You can extend it to 15 with `format long`. Check out [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/f1-5556.html) for more information about MATLAB precision

Comment: I don't think that has to do with the precision of the  floating point arithmetic representation of the number, I think it has to do with the machine epsilon, and possibly 1e-020 is less than the epsilon of the machine therefore can not be operated in MATLAB, but I'm not sure if the assumption is true

Comment: `format` only deals with how many digits are displayed as output to the console. It doesn't change the underlying number.